# Exception thrown when using generic arrays

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm having an ArrayStoreException which I don't understand in following scenario:

file List.java:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
class List<K> {
    K[] _list;
    K _dummy;
    int _size, _index;

    public List(int size) {
        _size = size;
        _index = 0;
        Class<?> cls = getClass();

        // as following is not allowed
        // _list = new K[size]; -->  cannot create a generic array of K
        // I'm doing the following instead
        _list = (K[])Array.newInstance(cls,size);
    }

    public void add(K obj) {
        _list[_index++] = obj;  // HERE'S THE EXCEPTION
                        //      java.lang.ArrayStoreException ??

        // IF I ASSIGN _dummy INSTEAD
        _list[_index++] = _dummy;   // NO ERROR
    }
} // class List
```

file mainLists.java:

```
public class mainLists {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        List<String> list = new List<String>(5);
        list.add("test");
    }
}
```

What the docs say about ArrayStoreException: 
"Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects"

but I'm passing a String type "test" to the method add() no?

what is the problem here?

thx

CHris

Answer (score 4):

Your array is an array of List, and not an array of K, since you instantiate it with

```
Array.newInstance(cls,size);
```

where `cls` is initialized with

```
Class<?> cls = getClass();
```

which returns the current object class, i.e. the class of `this`.

You can simply use an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`Class<?> cls = getClass();` will use current instance (`this`) to get Class object so later you are creating array of `List`s which will not accept `Strings`.

Maybe instead of guessing what type of array to create let user pass `Class` in `List` constructor which will be same as specified `K` type.

```
public List(int size, Class<K> clazz)
```